# implementation of insert function of Bucket hashing algorithm

Tags: c#

In the code below, doesn't it say, "if the array list does not contain the item then add it"?

```
public void Insert(string item)     
{    
    int hash_value;    
    hash_value = Hash(value);     
    if (data[hash_value].Contains(item))    
        data[hash_value].Add(item);    
}
```

If the item is already there, then why is it adding it again?

Comment: No, what the code says is, `"if the collection contains the item, try to add it again"`. You should have a `'!'` (which means `"not"`) in front of your `if` condition (just after the first parenthesis)

Comment: `hash_value = Hash(value);` does not compile. Where is `value` defined?

Comment: I got this code from (Data structure and algorithm using c#) written by MICHEAL McMILLAN

Comment: Read the [Reviews of that book on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Using-C/dp/0521670152#customerReviews). Sounds like a horrible book, and has the potential to lead you down some bad paths.

Comment: No that code is fine. That is how the bucket algorithm works. If the item's hash is present, then it gets the list (bucket) for that hash and adds another item to that bucket. But @rufusl is correct. I am actually one of the reviewers who left a negative review there. I read that book a few years ago and constantly heard myself saying wtf??

Comment: @CodingYoshi I will find anther book . thanks

Comment: @mjwills I did include it in the comments below

Comment: @CodingYoshi the code's not fine - I think you misread it. It's not checking whether the hash is present - it's checking whether the bucket contains the item, then adding the item to the bucket if it's already there(!)

Comment: @blorgbeard thanks for the heads up. Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The code as written says, "if the collection at the index of the hash of "value" contains "item", then try to add it again". You're missing a `'!'` in front of your `if` condition (which means `"not"`), like this:

```
public void Insert(string item)     
{    
    int hashValue = Hash(value);

    if (!data[hashValue].Contains(item)) data[hashValue].Add(item);    
}
```

---

Note that in your code snippet, `value` is undefined. It is entirely possible that you could get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if `hashValue` is greater than the number of items in the collection.

Also, `data` is undefined, so it's also possible that the item at `data[hashValue]` is `null`, in which case you'll get a `NullReferenceException` when trying to call `.Contains()` on it.

There are different ways to handle these issues, depending on the datatype of `data`. If it's an array of lists, for example, you could just not add anything if the hash is out of range, and you can initialize the list if it's `null`:

```
public void Insert(string item)     
{    
    int hashValue = Hash(value);

    if (hashValue < data.Length)
    {
        if (data[hashValue] == null) data[hashValue] = new List<string>();
        if (!data[hashValue].Contains(item)) data[hashValue].Add(item);    
    }
}
```

Comment: in bucket algorithm we are trying to handle collision which may happen happen when the hash function produce one key for 2 items.so one of the item will be deleted. in bucket algorithm we define array list of array lists so if the hash function produces one key for 2 or more items all of these item can be allocate without deleting any item.

Comment: so it is not the value issue here it is the insert function which got me wonder. i guess it is not mistake in the book . i guess i am the one who cant get . 
see the description of this part on the book

Comment: Ok? Just FYI, nobody uses `ArrayList` anymore (since .Net 1.1). Otherwise I think my answer still stands (except the last part, where I assumed you were using more current containers)

Comment: " A bucket is a simple data structure stored in a hash table element that
can store multiple items. In most implementations, this data structure is an
array, but in our implementation we’ll make use of an arraylist, which will
allow us not to worry about running out of space and to allocate more space."

Comment: In the end, this will make our implementation more efficient.
To insert an item, we first use the hash function to determine which arraylist
to store the item. Then we check to see if the item is already in the arraylist. If
it is we do nothing, if it’s not, then we call the Add method to insert the item
into the array list."

Comment: My friend, that book is 10 years old *and* is peppered with mistakes. Please learn from something recent, that is highly rated.

Comment: thank you so much . i was not sure if it is me who didn't get it or it is a mistake in the book.

Comment: can you recommend some books for me in the same field,please ??

Comment: I cannot personally, since I have been out of school and working for the last 15 years. :) I would say do a search on Amazon and look for high ratings with lots of reviews, and a publish date within the last couple of years. [This one](https://www.amazon.com/Learn-One-Day-Well-Hands/dp/1518800270/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1511828361&sr=1-12) looks like it might be good, but I have not read it.

Comment: @omaniaali [The best book ever](https://g.co/kgs/eXKdyX) Its a classic.

Comment: @CodingYoshi 
Thank you so much

Comment: @RufusL Thank you so much